# Create a blank table (array) of infinite rows and 25 columns in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create an un-initialized table or 2-d array of unlimited rows and 25 columns in Python:

```
table=pd.DataFrame({'A1':[],'A2':[],'A3':[] })
List_Column=['A1', 'A2'.....'A25']
```

But in above case, I have to manually enter the column names. Suppose I have List_Column, how can I update the column name from the List_Column?

Also,, at some point I want to update the blank array with a row from a list:

```
List_Row=['1', 'a', '25'.....'last']
```

So, that the final output looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do that. If you will add your data from a file, you will find more efficient ways to do that.

```
import pandas as pd

List_Column=['A1', 'A2', 'A25']
table = pd.DataFrame(columns = List_Column)

table['A'] = [1,2,3]
table['A2'] = ['A','B','C']

table
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) documentation, you can initialize a Dataframe using only the columns. This will default the index value if it isn't provided, but you can do

```py
pandas.DataFrame(column=List_Column)
```

From there you can add the rows in the way described by the [Pandas DataFrame.append() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append).